# Assign row as primary depending on the combination of columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID  Contract Type   Company
10000   Employee    Fake
10000   Contingent  Fake
10000   Employee    Fake
10001   Non-Worker  Fake5
10002   Employee    Fake4
10002   Employee    Fake4
10002   Employee    Fake4
10003   Contingent  Fake3
10003   Employee    Fake3
10003   Employee    Fake4
10003   Employee    Fake4
```

I need to create a column named "Primary Contract" that is set to "Yes" for the first unique combination it sees on ID, Contract Type and Company columns and set all the others to "No". As you can see, we may have duplicates in this columns.

The result expected would be this:

```
ID  Contract Type   Company Primary Contract
10000   Employee    Fake    Yes
10000   Contingent  Fake    Yes
10000   Employee    Fake    No
10001   Non-Worker  Fake5   Yes
10002   Employee    Fake4   Yes
10002   Employee    Fake4   No
10002   Employee    Fake4   No
10003   Contingent  Fake3   Yes
10003   Employee    Fake3   Yes
10003   Employee    Fake4   Yes
10003   Employee    Fake4   No
```

What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
mask = df.duplicated(subset=['ID','Contract Type','Company'])
df['Primary Contract'] = np.where(mask, 'No', 'Yes')
print (df)
       ID Contract Type Company Primary Contract
0   10000      Employee    Fake              Yes
1   10000    Contingent    Fake              Yes
2   10000      Employee    Fake               No
3   10001    Non-Worker   Fake5              Yes
4   10002      Employee   Fake4              Yes
5   10002      Employee   Fake4               No
6   10002      Employee   Fake4               No
7   10003    Contingent   Fake3              Yes
8   10003      Employee   Fake3              Yes
9   10003      Employee   Fake4              Yes
10  10003      Employee   Fake4               No
```